# HDD recovery after format

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, format

I recently installed Kali Linux next to win7 and win10 everything worked fine, but later I realised kali was not as useful and took a lot of space on my HDD so I deleted it and had 115GB of free space unavailable to use it in windows, so I went into CMD and used disk part to select the main disk and then the partition of the unallocate space, still no use, then I decided to select it again and clean it, instead of cleaning the partition, it wiped the whole drive, now it was unusable in win10 and needed to be formatted as NTFS and now all my important stuff are gone, I used Recuva with 24 files being shown but none in a way for a not than advance PC guy to read, all files are in $badClus, $Volume etc, nothing like program files. Users etc. how do I retrieve the files.
PS: I did not rewrite any data to the HDD as I don't want it to be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk
Testdisk from CGSecurity might be able to recreate your partitions.

If that fails get another drive, install windows, and use photorec to scrap all the files off the drive to the new drive.